# jquery add / remove select options reliable to other select

Tags: html, jquery, select

I have a select option with 1 person, 2 persons, 3 persons, 4 persons and so on.
Now I need to modify my other select option reliable to the maximum of selected persons with jquery.
If i.e. 4 persons are choosed in the first select menu, I need a maximum value of 4 in the next select.
If I choose back the 4 to 2 persons, the other select option need change to 2x as well.

I searched very much on stack overflow but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.
Best would be a for each function to create the values for the second select box.

Comment: Please include your HTML in the question along with the JS you've written in an attempt to achieve your goal. Please be aware that SO is here to help you debug code, not to write it for you

Comment: sure... i could copy paste a code for you from other questions but how could it help anybody?

Comment: Because it shows the context of the code you're working with, how you've setup any libraries you're using and also shows effort on your part.

Comment: `$("#guests").change(function () {
 $('#WP')
    .empty()
    .append('<option selected="1WP" value="1">1WP</option>');
});`

The Append part has to be in a forach from the persons select. But how i could do it the best way?

Comment: Here's some actual genuine help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is some code for now, if i test it without the loop it worked for a single value but with loop my whole jquery part with other functions dont work anymore:
`$("#people").change(function () {
 
valu = $(this).val();      
 $('#WP')      
  .empty()      
  for(var i = 0; i < valu; i++) {      
  .append('<option value="' + valu + '">' + valu + ' x</option>');        
 }      
});`      

Without the loop my WP select option changed reliable to the value og people from the first select input.
Anything i missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#people").change(function () {
   valu = $(this).val();
   $('#WP')
   .empty()
   var append = '';
   for(var i = 0; i <= valu; i++) {
      append += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + ' x</option>';
    
   }
   $('#WP').append(append);
});
```